# Can blob datatype be a file of .xml or .json?

Tags: sqlite, serialization

I use sqlite browser db ( it is my first database and i have no experience here ) . Class TelegramUser contains some fields and `ObservableCollection<string> messages`. I can easily represent in class TelegramUser fields such as Id and Name, but `ObservableCollection<string> messages` cannot be represented as TEXT or INTEGER datatype , so i found that in sqlite exists such datatype as BLOB and it can store files in binary format. I have such idea: serialize `ObservableCollection<string> messages` as .bin file and put into database as BLOB datatype. Can i put into BLOB datatype .xml , .json or .soap files too?

Comment: You want a table that contains an identifying element (a unique ID), a reference element (e.g. a user ID that relates to users stored in a separate table) and a data element (the message text itself, maybe also sent date and so on). You don't want a serialized representation of your object as a blob in your database, no matter how convenient it might seem to be.

Comment: Unless you had written me, i would try to serialize list and it would be nonsence,  but after your words i have known what to do now, thanks)